# TypeError when using storage plugin in cordova android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am newbie of phonegap development. Currently I am working on adding storage plugin to store data in the database. I am following the http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage but I am getting this error in my logcat:

```
D/CordovaLog( 1005): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1044 : processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Object #<Database> has no method 'executeSql'
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: which version of cordova are you building for. 1.8.1 is a very old version. The latest is 3.5. Please see the [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) for details on storage. You need to provide more details about your issue like your code snippet for a start. If you are using `window.opendatabase` API then you do not need any plugin.

Comment: @frank Yes, I am using latest version only, and I resolved it, the error is becuase i have some error while passing parameters to called function of db taransaction method. Now it is working. Thanks for Trying....